# What is wrong mounting an AngularJS and Java Spring application?

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to mount an AngularJS/Java application locally (developed by a friend), but I have problems with this, reading this you need to assume I have installed:

- Eclipse
- apache-tomcat-7
- jdk1.8
- and In the eclipse project I imported the BACK-END and no have warnings or errors.
- I mounted the BACK-END and FRONT-END in different folders in apache webapps directory.

The AngularJS application, is composed by the following:

**BACK-END**

Is a java project that has the following directory structure:

```
.settings
build
src
src/com/ProjectName/configuration
src/com/ProjectName/dashboard
src/com/ProjectName/events
src/com/ProjectName/infrastructure
src/com/ProjectName/util
src/app-config.properties [file]
src/Constans.java [file]
src/SprintConfiguration.java [file]
src/local-app-config.properties [file]
src/live-app-config.properties [file]
Webcontent (is empty)
.classpath [file]
.DS_store [file]
.gitignore [file]
.project [file]
```

I mounted this in `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName`

**FRONT-END**

This is the AngularJS application:
In the file: `conf.js` I have two variables to change:

```
var GLOBAL_BUCKET_URL = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/development.projectname.images";
var GLOBAL_SERVICES_URL = "http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/services";
```

I mounted this in `http://localhost:8080/project`

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/project`, the app shows a login form (fine), but immediately, in the console I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (No Encontrado)
```

So I click on login button in the application and shows this error in the console:

```
angular.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/services/users/token 404 (Not found)
```

I want to know, what I'm doing wrong, maybe there's missing directories (for example /services/users/token?)... Can you help?

Comment: *maybe there's missing directories (for example /services/users/token?)* Certainly looks like it.  Time to ask your friend

Comment: but remember the WebContent is empty... My question is why? back-end works like a service... maybe that's the reason that WebContent is empty, but how the server will bring service on http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/services/users/token if thw WebContent is empy!??